# Change sharepoint 2013 central admin language

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, language-pack, psconfig

I have installed a DEeutsch version of SharePoint 2013  -x64 mistakenly and want to change the central admin page's language to English.

I have installed the language pack,. The 1033 folder exists. and i have rerun the configuration wizard but the language has not been applied.

I have also tried this ps command : `psconfig.exe –cmd setup –lcid 1033`
but it returns error.

> There was one more solution about 'Webs' table in db

which i could not find that table. I think its because i just installed SP and there is no site there yet. 
Could someone please help me to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to reinstall SharePoint in english language. Just changing the CA's language won't change the language of ULS-Logs and other stuff. This makes troubleshooting much more challenging, as there is no german-speaking SharePoint community.

Comment: yeah I finally reinstalled that :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way to change the Language of central admin.by default, the language of central admin is the language of sharepoint version installed.

If you want to change it then re install the sharepoint with correct language version.

To change language in web table is not supported and will end support contract with MSFT. But if it is ur Dev environment then you can play with it. Open the central admin content db(mostly it is sharepoint admin GUIs) and you will see the web table under the tables.